# get id in joint query

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two tables. First for products and second for order

product

```
id |Product name

01 |Computer
02 |Mobile
03 |Tablet
```

and second table for order

```
p_id | username

02   | Joe
02   | Mike
01   | Joe
03   | Tomy
```

Now I want to show those products to user which are not purchased yet by user
lets suppose login username is Mike

```
$username = "Mike";
$get = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT e.id 
FROM `products` AS e INNER JOIN `order` AS u ON u.p_id = e.id WHERE e.username != '$username' ");
echo mysqli_num_rows($get);

Result 3;
```

the above query count all order where username is not mike and show the result.. i want only those product list which are not purchased by "Mike"

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: In your query's WHERE clause ,you've got `e.username != '$username'` but `e` is an alias for products table but products table doesn't have a `username` column. name your aliases properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to do an Anti-Join

```
SELECT * FROM product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM order o WHERE o.username = 'Mike' AND p.id = o.p_id
)
```

More information on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if i understand your problem correctly, but i assume you want to do this:

```
$notThisUser = "Mike";
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT productname FROM product 
    WHERE id IN (SELECT p_id FROM order WHERE username != ?)");
$sql->bind_param("s", $notThisUser);
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($productName);

while ($sql->fetch()) {
    echo $productName;
}
```

Comment: This would actually be quiet slow as you would select all other users, which is a bigger result, so the query planner has to do more compares

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are aiming at.

```
$username = "Mike";
$selectQuery = "select p.id from product
inner join oder AS o on o.p_id=p.id where o.username <> :username";
$statement = $dbh->prepare($selectQuery);
$statement->bindValue(":username", $username);
$statement->execute();
$data = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: And how exactly is this different from the original question (bearing in mind that `<>` is transmutable with `!=`

Answer (score -1):

you should Go with select * FROM `product` WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `p_id` FROM `order` WHERE `user_name`='Mike') thats all

Comment: Why, how it helps, nice formatting. Thats all. [answer] in [help]

Comment: It's pretty close to my answer, as it is a type of anti-join but `NOT EXISTS` is type-less, since the db does not have to compare 2 values.